# What is the spot on the BBC Weather background?

Tags: production

Its just a personal curiosity. I have noticed (I don't know if anyone else has) a spot in the background of BBC weather forecast. This spot can be seen only when the circle appears at the beginning and at the end as you can see in the images where I have circled in red colour.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Can anyone tell me what is the spot? It seems like a reflection of a light but I am still unsure about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image used for the BBC Weather "welcoming" screen is a digital composite of a real glass sphere, mapped with whatever the predominant weather conditions are.

The shape there is from the lighting used to photograph the actual glass sphere.  This looks to me as though it's a studio light with barn doors

[image]

Of course, distortions produced by the sphere mess with the reflection, making it hard to see the shape of it exactly.

More about the graphical production of the BBC Weather items can be read here

[BBC Weather - 3D weather graphics for real time forecasts](https://www.mikeafford.com/tv-graphics/projects/weather-graphics.html)